# OpenGL sheared near clipping plane

Tags: opengl, projection, clipping, projection-matrix

I have four arbitrary points (lt,rt,rb,lb) in 3d space and I would like these points to define my near clipping plane (lt stands for left-top, rt for right-top and so on).
Unfortunately, these points are not necessarily a rectangle (in screen space). They are however a rectangle in world coordinates.

The context is that I want to have a mirror surface by computing the mirrored world into a texture. The mirror is an arbitary translated and rotated rectangle in 3d space.
I do not want to change the texture coordinates on the vertices, because that would lead to ugly pixelisation when you e.g. look at the mirror from the side. When I would do that, also culling would not work correctly which would lead to huge performance impacts in my case (small mirror, huge world).

I also cannot work with the stencil buffer, because in some scenarios I have mirrors facing each other which would also lead to a huge performance drop. Furthermore, I would like to keep my rendering pipeline simple.

Can anyone tell me how to compute the according projection matrix?

Edit: Of cause I already have moved my camera accordingly. That is not the problem here.

Comment: I don't think you can change the near clipping plane to any other arbitrary plane, just with a projection matrix. It's always a minimum Z value. Maybe there's a way to do it but it would still mess up your depth buffer since everything on the minimum clipping plane would have to have minimum Z.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tweaking the projection matrix (which I don't think can be done in the general case), you should define an additional clipping plane. You do that by enabling:

```
glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
```

And then set [`gl_ClipDistance`](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_ClipDistance.xhtml) vertex shader output to be the distance of the vertex from the mirror:

```
gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(vec4(vertex_position, 1.0), mirror_plane);
```

Comment: I cannot see how to compute the color of the according pixel in the texture with this solution.

Comment: @user1994405 what does it have to do with clipping?

Comment: Nothing. The oblique clipping works fine. I'm asking for oblique color and depth buffers and not for oblique clipping. As I said, I just want use the framebuffer as a texture without changing texture coordinates.

Comment: Maybe, it does not work without using the stencil buffer as @user253751 said. That would be unfortunate, because rendering endless reflections can get pretty tricky.

Comment: @user1994405 huh? I don't understand you. The way you normally do that is by rendering with a stencil buffer with the same projection as your camera, but with the world (or camera) mirrored through the mirror surface. As for multiple reflections -- there isn't much you can do beyond rendering multiple times. Each reflection causes a completely different projection (unless you have some very regular geometry, like square rooms). The normal way to deal with this is to darken your reflections, so after a few you can simply fill with solid color.